# Tensor Product of Modules over R and a subring S

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

If we have a commutative Ring R with a subring S and two R-Modules (or S-Modules). What can we say about the correlations between $$ M \otimes_R  N \quad and \quad M \otimes_S N \quad ?$$ 
Wikipedia says, since S is a subring of R there exists a Homomorphism $f: R \to S $ and we can say that we get a surjective Homomorphism $ M\otimes_R N \to M\otimes_S N$.   I don't see why this Homomorphism is surjective. I thought that $ M\otimes_R N$ might be smaller than $ M\otimes_S N$ since S has less Elements, so there are less limitations for $\otimes_S$.

Comment: You got it a bit wrong. Since $S$ is a subring of $R$, there exists an inclusion homomorphism $f : S \to R$, so you get a surjective homomorphism $M \otimes_S N \to M \otimes_R N$ (note that $S$ and $R$ are swapped in the Wikipedia article). Your intuition is correct.